# MySql | How to compute this

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this table

```
Grade        Lec         Lab
1.5           3           0
1.5           3           0
1.5           2           1
```

The formula will be like this

```
1.5 * 3
1.5 * 3
1.5 * (2+1) = 13.5 / 9 = 1.5
```

13.5 is the total then 9 is the total sum of the lec + lab

What query should I use?

How can i add this to query WHERE Lec + Lab = 15. If lec + lab is 15 above will show but if lower than 15 it will not show then i want to limit the show in 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Grade * (Lec + Lab)) / SUM(Lec + Lab) FROM t;
```

> ```
> | SUM(Grade * (Lec + Lab)) / SUM(Lec + Lab) |
> | ----------------------------------------: |
> |                                       1.5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=96ae2c71b6b4b0ce03a29f1ede143efa)*

Answer (score 0):

using the previous answer 
you can use a subquery to achieve the additional filter

```
select grade from (select sum(grade * (lec + lab)) / sum(lec + lab) from t) as final where grade >= 15
```

or
just use having 
`SELECT (SUM(Grade * (Lec + Lab)) / SUM(Lec + Lab)) as grade FROM t having grade >= 15;`

in addition, you can use 
grade * (
case 
 when Lec > 0 then Lec + Lab
 when Lec < 0 then Lec - Lab 
 else Lec
end )

you can read about having clause [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

Comment: The sum of Lec and Lab will filter if the total of Lec and Lab is 15 above it will show but if its lower than 15 it will not show

Comment: You mean that if the sum(lac + lab) is less than 15 then we don't need to make the calculation?
in that case, we can change the having clause to sum(lec+lab) >=15

Comment: Yeah so i will put in WHERE SUM(lec+lab) >= 15?

Comment: you can't use where clause because sum is an aggregative function
you should use having, take a look:SELECT SUM(Grade * (Lec + Lab)) / SUM(Lec + Lab) FROM t having sum(lec + lab)>=15;